# How to update `BehaviorSubject` single value alone

Tags: angular, angular5

In my `BehaviorSubject` the address element having 2 property. In this how to update a single property alone?

here is my try:

```
myAddress:any = {
    "plot":32,
    "street":"D15 Road"
  }

  private address = new BehaviorSubject(this.myAddress);
  addressClass = this.address.asObservable();


  updateAddress(newAddress){
    this.address.next(newAddress);
  }
```

I am trying to update like this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedObject } from './shared.object';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
    <h2>City Name in Hero : {{heroName}}</h2>
    <h3>{{plotNo}}</h3>
    <button (click)="updatePlot(44)">Update Ploat </button>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  @Input() name: string;

  plotNo:number;
  address:any;


  constructor(private shared:SharedObject){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
     this.shared.addressClass.subscribe((address) => {
       this.plotNo = address.plot;
     })
  }


  updatePlot(newNo){
    this.shared.updateAddress(newNo); //don't know how to update plot no alone?
  }

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use spread operator and the BehaviorSubjects value like this :

```
updateAddress(newAddress){
  this.address.next({...this.address.value, ...newAddress});
}
```

[Here is a stackblitz demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50393901)

Comment: I agree. In case if this is 2 values, we can mange any way. in case if the object having more than 50 values... how to handle that?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the spread operator will replace only values in object `newAddress` and keep the initial value of the address.